# Decimal to hex conversion in Perl (&#8211; to &#x2013;)

Tags: perl

I have an HTML file with many numerical entities. I want to change them them from using decimal numbers to hex numbers. For example: I want `&#8211;` (en dash) changed to to `&#x2013;`.

How does one do this using Perl?

I have tried using the following code:

```
use String::HexConvert ':all';
my $text = "this is text&#8211;example";

print ascii_to_hex($text);
```

It will converting the all characters. I want to convert the `&#8211;` only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$text =~ s/\&#(\d+);/"&#x".sprintf("%x",$1).";"/eg
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick:

```
$html =~ s/&#([0-9]+);/ sprintf("&#x%x;", $1) /eg;
```

(`\d` matches too many characters.)

Answer (score 0):

To convert from hex to decimal:

```
$html =~ s/&#(x[0-9A-Fa-f]+);/ sprintf("&#%d;", hex($1)) /eg;
```